# How to get attribute from element using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here's a bit html from a web page:

```
<bg-quote class="value negative" field="Last" format="0,0.00" channel="/zigman2/quotes/203558040/composite,/zigman2/quotes/203558040/lastsale" data-last-stamp="1624625999626" data-last-raw="671.68">671.68</bg-quote>
```

So I want to get the value of attribute "data-last-raw", but find() -method seems to return None when searching for this element. Why is this and how can I fix it?

My code and Traceback below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import tkinter as tk


class Scraping:

    @classmethod
    def get_to_site(cls, stock_name):
        sitename = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/tsla' + stock_name
        site = requests.get(sitename, headers={
            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language":"en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,ml;q=0.7",
            "Connection":"keep-alive",
            "Host":"www.marketwatch.com",
            "Referer":"https://www.marketwatch.com",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36"
        })
        print(site.status_code)
        src = site.content
        Scraping.get_price(src)
        
    @classmethod
    def get_price(cls, src):
        soup = BS(src, "html.parser")
        price_holder = soup.find("bg-quote", {"channel":"/zigman2/quotes/203558040/composite,/zigman2/quotes/203558040/lastsale"})
        price = price_holder["data-last-raw"]
        print(price)



Scraping.get_to_site('tsla')


200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit\stock_price_scraper.py", line 41, in <module>
    Scraping.get_to_site('tsla')
  File "c:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit\stock_price_scraper.py", line 30, in get_to_site
    Scraping.get_price(src)
  File "c:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit\stock_price_scraper.py", line 36, in get_price
    price = price_holder["data-last-raw"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

So site.status_code returns 200 to indicate that the site is opened correctly, but I think the soup.find() -method returns None to indicate that the element I was looking for was not found.

Somebody pls help!

Comment: can you post the full traceback and separate out the error from the code

Comment: ```PS C:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit> & C:/Python39ni/python.exe c:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/stock_price_scraper.py
200
    Scraping.get_to_site('tsla')
  File "c:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit\stock_price_scraper.py", line 30, in get_to_site
    Scraping.get_price(src)
  File "c:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit\stock_price_scraper.py", line 36, in get_price
    price = price_holder["data-last-raw"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: @AatuTahkola please [edit] your question and include the traceback within it

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(ticker):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/{ticker}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('bg-quote.value:nth-child(2)').text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('tsla')
```

Output:

```
670.99
```